# cannot import function from module

Tags: python, pygame, python-import

I import this module in the main program with the line `from classe_recto2 import Recto`. It will import the class Recto (I can print a class Recto object) but when I call the function next_circle I get `NameError: name 'next_circle' is not defined`.
The whole module looks like this:

```
import pygame

class Recto:
    
    def __init__(self,posizione, colore,snippet,circles_list, counter_snippet, volume):
        self.posizione = posizione
        self.colore = colore
        self.snippet = snippet
        self.cerchi = circles_list
        self.counter_snippet = counter_snippet
        self.volume = volume
        self.first_position = self.cerchi[0][0]
        self.position = self.cerchi[0][1]
        self.height = self.cerchi[0][2]
        self.direzione = self.cerchi[0][3]
   
    def snippet_volume(self):
        pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(self.snippet, self.volume)
        
    def next_circle(self):
        circle = []
        if self.height == 0:
            new_height = 0
            self.height = new_height
        else:    
            new_height = self.height -2
            self.height = new_height
        if self.direzione == 1 and self.position < self.first_position +100:
            new_position = self.position+10
            self.position = new_position
            if new_position > self.first_position +100:
                new_position = self.first_position +100
                self.position = new_position
                self.direzione = -1
            else:    
                self.direzione = 1
        if self.position == self.first_position +100:
            new_position = self.position -10
            self.position = new_position
            self.direzione = -1
        if self.direzione == -1 and self.position > self.first_position:
            new_position = position -10
            if new_position < self.first_position:
                new_position = self.first_position
                self.position = new_position
                self.direzione= 1
            else:    
                self.direzione = -1
        if self.direzione == -1 and self.position == self.first_position:    
            new_position = self.position+10
            self.position = new_position
            self.direzione = 1
        circle.append(self.first_position)
        circle.append(new_position)
        circle.append(new_height)
        circle.append(self.direzione)
        return circle
```

Sorry, I know it is a lot of code but I thought being able to see it all could make it easier to
pinpoint the problem. Thank you.

Comment: how do you call next_circle? could you show your program which import the class and call the function?

Comment: `next_circle()` is not a function, it's a method on objects of that class, so you'd have to have an instance of the class (e.g. `recto = Recto(<some values>)`) and then call the method on it like `recto.next_circle()`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Calling recto.next_circle() (after instantiating it)in the main program solves the problem. I had totally misunderstood the way class methods work. That really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from a missconception of classes.

Here is a simple snippet that reproduce your error :

```py
class Example():
    def example_method(self):
        print("example")

example_method()
```

Output :

> NameError: name 'example_method' is not defined

The problem has nothing to do with imports, rather it's a matter of understanding that methods inside your class can not be called this way.

---

A class describes something, and the methods describe what this something can do. For instance :
If we want to write a simple class for a duck :
A duck has a **name**, a **weight** or anything you could need to describe a duck in the context of your program.
And we want to tell our program that a duck can quack so we will write a method for it.

**Here is how this translate to code:**

```py
class Duck():
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
    
    def quack(self):
        print("quack")
```

Now to use the class at all you will need to create an instance of the class :
Here we will create a duck named **"bob"** (which weights 12kg, yeah.. impressive, I know)

```py
bob = Duck("bob", 12)
```

And now we can make bob quack by writing :

```py
bob.quack()
```

But if you just do :

```py
quack()
```

Your program has no clue what you are trying to do (and me neither tbh) so it tells you :

> NameError: name 'quack' is not defined

Here is where your error comes from, it is not an import issue :)

By the way, here are a few additionnal tips for you :

When programming, stick to one language (preferably english) but here you mix english and italian (if I'm not mistaken) which is very bad for code readability and code comprehension

The content of your `next_circle()` function was irrelevant for your question. I know it can be hard to tell if you are a begginer but you could have figured it out by replacing all the code inside by something like `print("test")` and you would have noticed that your error was still here. Hence the content of the function cannot be the source of the issue and is not relevant to show in your question. What would have been great to show us was your other file where you `import Recto` and try to call your method

When you encounter a problem, get the habit of reproducing the same error with as little code as possible, this way it will shed light on the source of your issue

When you have a really long methods like `next_circle()` it is a good indicator that the method should be simplified and/or split into multiple methods. In the present case you could shorten it by just writing it differently

Happy programming